# Very slow execution of user defined convolution function for neural network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution, fixed-point

I have an implementation of a convolution neural network in MATLAB (from the open source DeepLearnToolbox). The following code finds the convolution of different weights and parameters:

```
 z = z + convn(net.layers{l - 1}.a{i}, net.layers{l}.k{i}{j}, 'valid');
```

To update the tool, I have implemented my own fixed-point scheme based convolution using the following code:

```
function result = convolution(image, kernal)

% find dimensions of output
row = size(image,1) - size(kernal,1) + 1;
col = size(image,2) - size(kernal,2) + 1;
zdim = size(image,3);

%create output matrix
output = zeros(row, col);

% flip the kernal
kernal_flipped = fliplr(flipud(kernal));

%find rows and col of kernal for loop iteration
row_ker = size(kernal_flipped,1);
col_ker = size(kernal_flipped,2);

for k = 1 : zdim
    for i = 0 : row-1
        for j = 0 : col-1
            sum = fi(0,1,8,7);
             prod = fi(0,1,8,7);
            for k_row = 1 : row_ker
                for k_col = 1 : col_ker
                    a = image(k_row+i, k_col+j, k);
                    b = kernal_flipped(k_row,k_col);
                    prod = a * b;
                   % convert to fixed point                     
                    prod = fi((product/16384), 1, 8, 7);

                    sum = fi((sum + prod), 1, 8, 7);
                end
            end
            output(i+1, j+1, k) = sum;
        end
    end
end

result = output;
end
```

The problem is that when I use my convolution implementation in the bigger application, it is super slow.
Any suggestions how to improve its execution time?

Comment: Use MATLAB’s `conv2` function. You won’t be able to write anything faster than that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: The default implementation already uses "convn" function. I want to replace it with my own implementation of convolution.

Comment: To learn how it works? Or do you have other reasons? You can’t write a fast convolution in MATLAB, and even if you wrote it yourself in a compiled language like C it would still be slower than `conv2`.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB doesn't support fixed point 2D convolution, but knowing that convolution can be written as matrix multiplication and that MATLAB has support for [fixed point matrix multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/mtimes.html) you can use [`im2col`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) to convert the image into column format and multiply it by the kernel to convolve them.

```
row = size(image,1) - size(kernal,1) + 1;
col = size(image,2) - size(kernal,2) + 1;
zdim = size(image,3);

output = zeros(row, col);

kernal_flipped = fliplr(flipud(kernal));

fi_kernel = fi(kernal_flipped(:).', 1, 8, 7) / 16384;   

sz = size(kernal_flipped);
sz_img = size(image);

% Use the generated indexes to convert the image into column format
idx_col = im2col(reshape(1:numel(image)/zdim,sz_img(1:2)),sz,'sliding');
image = reshape(image,[],zdim);

for k = 1:zdim
    output(:,:,k) = double(fi_kernel * reshape(image(idx_col,k),size(idx_col)));
end
```